# How can i fetch the last value inserted into sqlite Database

Tags: android

I have a doubt to be clarified. How can i fetch the last value inserted into sqlite DB. I need code for that.I tried using query like this:

```
SELECT uname,umessage,utime FROM chatmessage ORDER BY utime DESC limit 1;
```

Where am i doing wrong?? I need help in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the value is last its id should be maximum

you can fire the query like this

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT uname,umessage,utime FROM tablename WHERE " +
                "Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM tablename ); ",null);
```

for last message by particular user add user id column in the message table like

```
id | userid | message | utime


1  |   1    | wlhf    | 3:10

2  |   3    | dfhhfjh | 2:15

3  |   1    | kjfedhr | 4:00

4  |   2    | hejhe   | 1:15

5  |   3    |  kegekr | 3:30

6  |   1    | wlhf    | 3:10

7  |   3    | dfhhfjh | 2:15

8  |   1    | kjfedhr | 4:00

9  |   2    | hejhe   | 1:15

10  |   3    |  kegekr | 3:30




c = db.rawQuery("
select message  from table1 where 


userid  = 1 ; ",null);




recieve like



ArrayList<String> listMessg = new ArrayList<String>();



cursor = dbm.columnValueofCourse();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

    reciv = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("message"));
listMessg.add(reciv_Par);
}

int sizeoflist = listMessg.size();

because in ascending order , the last index 
of array list will be the last message of the user

System.out.println("THE LAST MESSAGE BY USER IS  " + listMessg.et(sizeoflist -1));
```

Comment: wonderful answer.. Thanks a lot friend. worked well. I also have one more doubt. I need to fetch the last message sent by individual buddy. how can i get that. Using the above code i can get the last value inserted in sqlite. Same way i need to get the last value (message) sent by individual buddy. can u please help me in this issue . Thanks

Comment: @user1265623 i don not know how you are handling your database for a user but i can suggest one thing if you have a user id make it a column in table of messages and fire query on basis of it and receive it in an array,the last index will have the last message by that user

Comment: I am not clearly getting what you are saying. Can u please simplify and tell me the query i need to give.

Comment: hi.. I need to know how to query the following.. I have plenty of friends in my sqlite DB table. i need to fetch last message sent by individual friend from by DB. ie. last message from my individual friend my contact list. i need SELECT the data and fetch the value.. how can i write the query

Answer (score 1):

SQLiteDatabase returns id of inserted row. You can rememember this id in some value and use it.

```
long lastId = db.insert(......);
```